# Add watermark on top of form fields

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have this code that will add a watermark on each page:

```
string watermarkLocation = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Watermark.png";

Document document = new Document();
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileLocation);
PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(fileLocation.Replace(".pdf", "_marked.pdf"), FileMode.Create));

iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(watermarkLocation);
img.ScaleToFit(document.PageSize);
img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 100); 

PdfContentByte waterMark;
for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
{
    waterMark = stamp.GetOverContent(page);
    waterMark.AddImage(img);
}
stamp.FormFlattening = true;
stamp.Close();
return fileLocation.Replace(".pdf", "_marked.pdf");
```

But on PDFs that have textboxes, the image will go behind the textbox/form. I thought flattening the file will fix this, but it does not work.

[image: Screenshot]

I used a full image as a test but the watermark in the end will have transparency.

Comment: *"thought flattening the file will fix this, but it does not work."* - flattening will fix it, but you have to flatten in a first pass and apply the watermark in a second pass.

Comment: @mkl I've added the code solution but your suggestion worked. I was flattening it before adding the stamp but what worked for me was creating separate stamp for flattening then another one for adding the watermark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the final code I'm using. As my comment mentioned, there's basically 2 readers/stamps, one to flatten the file and another to add the watermark.

Flatten file:

```
private byte[] FlattenPdfFormToBytes(PdfReader reader)
{
    var memStream = new MemoryStream();
    var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, memStream) { FormFlattening = true };
    stamper.Close();
    return memStream.ToArray();
}
```

Add Watermark (which will call FlattenPdfFormToBytes):

```
    public string AddWatermark(string fileLocation)
    {
        string watermarkLocation = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Watermark.png";

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileLocation);
        PdfReader pdfFlatten = new PdfReader(FlattenPdfFormToBytes(pdfReader)); // The secret sauce is this!!!

        PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(pdfFlatten, new FileStream(fileLocation.Replace(".pdf", "_marked.pdf"), FileMode.Create));

        iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(watermarkLocation);
        img.ScaleToFit(document.PageSize);
        img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 100);

        PdfContentByte waterMark;
        for (int page = 1; page <= pdfFlatten.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            waterMark = stamp.GetOverContent(page);
            waterMark.AddImage(img);
        }

        stamp.Close();
        return fileLocation.Replace(".pdf", "_marked.pdf");
    }
```